Meaning of a particular Mathematical symbol ($^\bot$) in Linear Algebra
While reading about Unitary Transformation between two sets of basis vectors of a vector space, I encountered the symbol $V^\bot$. Where, V is a Vector Space. What is its meaning?
Thanks in advance.

Orthogonal complement $(?)$

See Orthogonal complement

If that symbol is used in a textbook without definition anywhere, then it is probably not a very good textbook.

“The” List of $\ldots$.
